# Quotienting a square with a grid inside

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, visualization

The following is meant to be a depiction of quotienting a square by each of its sides, with a grid inside. I want to preserve the intersection points in the grid. I first quotient each side of the square. Then, I identify the black point with the green point, and the pink point with the yellow point.

Let $X$ be the original square. Then I was able to write down $X/ \sim = \{ [x] : x \in X \},$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x.$ I'm stuck at this point.

What is the final topological shape homeomorphic to?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the picture in 3D then be an octahedron inscribed in the cube (i.e. its dual polyhedron) with opposite vertices connected by curved segments (the distorted grid), e.g. top and bottom connected by blue, left and right by red, and front and back by green? Would the recipe in $n$ dimensions be to consider the dual polytope of the $n$-cube (the $n$-cross-polytope)?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here. Why do you mention the grid if you're only interested in the topology of the quotient?

Comment: It's also not clear to me what kind of answer you're looking for. The quotient isn't even $T_1$, so probably it doesn't admit a nice description as a familiar space.

Comment: As far as I understood, when you quotient each side of the square you also have to quotient all its vertices into one point, so you have to quotient the boundary of the square into a point. Then the black, green, pink, and yellow points are already glued together and the obtained space seems to be homeomorphic to a sphere.